# Invoke-CIMMethod from list - SCCM apps install

Tags: powershell, sccm

I use the below to lazily install SCCM apps from Software Center for end users on non mandatory apps, however it's not working when trying to do it across multiple machines:

```
$computer = Get-Content -Path c:\temp\computers.txt

foreach ($computer in $computers) {
  $appName = 'AppNameHere'
    
  $Application = (Get-CimInstance `
    -ClassName CCM_Application `
    -Namespace "root\ccm\clientSDK" `
    -ComputerName $computer | 
    Where-Object {$_.Name -like $AppName}
  )
    
  $Args = @{
    EnforcePreference = [UINT32] 0
    Id = "$($Application.id)"
    IsMachineTarget = $Application.IsMachineTarget
    IsRebootIfNeeded = $False
    Priority = 'High'
    Revision = "$($Application.Revision)"
  }
    
  $Instance = @(Get-CimInstance -ClassName CCM_Application `
    -Namespace "root\ccm\clientSDK" -ComputerName $Computer |
      Where-Object {$_.Name -like $AppName})

    Invoke-CimMethod -Namespace ROOT\ccm\ClientSDK `
      -ClassName CCM_Application `
      -ComputerName $computer `
      -MethodName Install `
      -Arguments $Args |
      ft -AutoSize
    
}
```

If I remove the foreach, it will get the computers from the list but only process if the .txt contains one machine of course. As it stands, it will run with no errors, but not action anything and produce no output. Feel like I'm missing something really obvious.

I did try invoking the above using Invoke-Command, but it returned a host of WS errors - I don't think we need to Invoke it anyway using Invoke-CimMethod?

Would be grateful for any help - thanks all.

Comment: Seems like it would work with the exception of advising you to assign your arguments to a different variable than `$args`, and fixing the typo in your `$computer = Get-Content...` to `$computers`.

Comment: Abraham, you're a hero! It was literally only the typo in $computers stopping this... Was racking my brain going insane. Fresh eyes always help. Thanks a lot Abraham, appreciate you taking a look.

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is old, and I hope that you have found your answer by now. But, if not, here is something that should hopefully help.

You have to make sure that PowerShell understands that it needs to expect an array, and not just a single string.

Try changing the following line
`$computer = Get-Content -Path c:\temp\computers.txt`
to
`$computer=@(Get-Content -Path "C:\temp\computers.txt")`

Also, make sure the test file is properly formatted such as below:

```
COMPUTER1
COMPUTER2
COMPUTER3
COMPUTER4
COMPUTER5
COMPUTER6
```

If that doesn't work, also check to see that your text file is encoded in UTF-8 and not some other encoding.

Good luck.